# SQL query for last entries in a period

Tags: sql, oracle, frequency, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write a SQL query for Oracle SQL in order to retrieve the last records for a certain period frequency.  For example, say the frequency is Quarterly, (I'd also like monthly and annually to work), I can provide the start dates and end dates for the quarters if necessary, but I need to retrieve the last entry within each quarter.  How can I do this?  I've had limited luck so far without writing lots of subqueries.

Comment: Can you post the queries you have tried? And if possible the table structures you are querying, so everyone has a better understanding of the problem and give you a better answer

Comment: Yaroslav is right, you should post sample table structures.

Comment: +1 to Mark for a nice use of `partition by`. To the OP: why not to simply restrict by time range and select the row with max(id) ?

Comment: The table structure is pretty simple, I'm going to want to select a timeseries of data based on a series name and id number, and between two dates, each of which is a column.  Then I'm going to want to get the last value of another column at regular date-based intervals as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by trunc(date_field, 'MON') 
                           order by date_field desc) rn
 from my_table t)
where rn = 1
```

for months. (Use 'Q' or 'Y' instead of 'MON' in the `trunc` clause for quarters or years.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3...colN
FROM TableA
WHERE  (colX = (SELECT     MAX(Date) AS LastDate
    FROM          TableA 
    WHERE      QuarterDate Between (BeginningDate AND EndingDate)
```

colX is the date column that is your date you need to be checking if in the quarter.

I think that should work.